# ConTeXt: Using system-installed TrueType/OpenType fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, context, context-mkiv

I'm trying to use Cambria for text and Calibri for headings in a ConTeXt document, but I don't understand what is happening at all, nothing seems to have any effect and in the end it falls back to LMRoman/LMSans.

As a minimal starting point, I'm trying to recreate this document. I can just compile it with `lualatex` and it finds my fonts, they are installed system-wide through fontconfig. `pdffonts` shows that two TrueType faces from each family are embedded, nothing else.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\begin{document}
Cambria \textsf{Calibri}
\emph{Cambria \textsf{Calibri}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

How do I create this document using ConTeXt? I tried this:

```
\setupbodyfont[Cambria]
%no idea how to set sans
\starttext
Cambria \sans{Calibri}
\em{Cambria \sans{Calibri}}
\stoptext
```

[image: output2]

But only got LM, the log contained an error about `loc`, which isn't mentioned in my file, is this a bug in the typefile? It seems to try to do something with the argument but fails before loading...

```
fonts           > typescripts > unknown library 'loc'
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/type-imp-cambria.mkiv)
```

As far as I understand, both fontspec and ConTeXt use luatex' facilities to locate and load the fonts, so I don't have to install them manually, is that true? In my installation, `type-otf.mkiv` is empty except for a comment claiming that it's unnecessary since OTF fonts can be found by name.

---

With

```
\setupbodyfont[libertine]
\starttext ...
```

[image: output3]

I get Biolinum as the roman font and Libertine as sans, but only for the first `\sans`, everything in `\em` is roman.

Comment: OT: Note that `\em` is a font switch, so you have to use `{\em .... }`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are three ways to use system fonts.

1. Write your own typescript. ConTeXt comes with the typescripts for most system fonts. See `type-imp-*.mkiv` for details. For example, the typescript for calibra is defined in `type-imp-calibra.mkiv` and the typescript for `calibiri` is defined in `type-imp-cleartype.mkiv`. To use them, you need to define your own typescript that sets the serif and sans serif fonts. For example (not that `\em` is font switch, not a font command):

   ```
   \usetypescriptfile[cleartype]

   \starttypescript[mainface]
     \definetypeface  [mainface] [rm] [serif] [cambria] [default]
     \definetypeface  [mainface] [ss] [sans]  [calibri] [default]
     \definetypeface  [mainface] [tt] [mono]  [consolas][default]
     \definetypeface  [mainface] [mm] [math]  [cambria] [default]
   \stoptypescript

   \setupbodyfont[mainface]

   \starttext
   Cambria \sans{Calibri}
   {\em Cambria \sans{Calibri}}
   \stoptext
   ```

   which gives

   [image]
2. The other option is to use the `simplefonts` module, which will automatically create appropriate typescript fonts. For example:

   ```
   \usemodule[simplefonts]

   \setmainfont[Cambria]
   \setsansfont[Calibri]
   ```

   which gives the same result as before.
3. In recent versions of ConTeXt MKIV the `simplefonts` module has been superseded by `\definefontfamily` which is part of the core.

   ```
   \definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [Cambria]
   \definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [Calibri]
   \definefontfamily [mainface] [tt] [Consolas]
   \definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [Asana Math]

   \setupbodyfont[mainface]
   ```

   This has the same effect as the above.  Keep in mind though that you have to  set *all* typefaces, i.e. `rm`, `ss`, `tt`, `mm`.  Otherwise strange things might happen.

Comment: Simplefonts looks great, however using your example, everything is set in LMMonoPropLt10-Regular for me and the log complains `simplefonts     > font ''cambria'' not found` and `simplefonts     > font ''calibri'' not found`

Comment: The typescript example produces empty output, not even using the LM fallback, and I get `font with asked name 'cambria' is not found using lookup 'name'` and `font with asked name 'calibri' is not found using lookup 'file'`

Comment: running with `OSFONTDIR=~/.fonts` doesn't change anything, but giving the exact subfolder which contains cambria.ttc etc as `OSFONTDIR=~/.fonts/fonts/microsoft/` it works fully for typescript, italics missing for simplefonts.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. After running `OSFONTDIR=~/.fonts/fonts/microsoft/ mtxrun --script fonts --reload` I can just run `context` without setting `OSFONTDIR` and simplefonts even finds the italics. Just running `mtxrun --script fonts --reload` again deletes the cache and only finds fonts in `/usr/local/texlive/2013/`. I expected that script to use my system's fontconfig paths, as lualatex appears to do.

Comment: You need to either set OSFFONTDIR in your `.bashrc` file, or in the `texmfcnf.lua` file for the affect to be permanent.

Comment: I think the order of examples should be different. Simplefonts solution should be given in the first place. There is hardly any need for typescripts anymore unless you need a very unusual setup.

Answer (score 4):

### As easy as executing the following command...

If your [`OSFONTDIR`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX#Building_the_font_database) environment variable is [set correctly](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX#Building_the_font_database), then installing (new) system fonts in modern versions of ConTeXt should be as easy as executing the following command:

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts --reload
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed