# ConTeXt only finds one font style in .ttc file

Tags: fonts, context, context-mkiv, truetype

I've been trying to use a couple of my Mac system fonts in my document, and I'm finding that ConTeXt is only finding one style for a couple of the fonts I've been using.  The ones I've tried are Baskerville and Optima.

```
\definefontfamily[myfamily][serif][Baskerville]
\definefontfamily[myfamily][sans][Optima]
\setupbodyfont[myfamily]
```

With this preamble, all of the serif text is typeset as bold, no matter what font switch I use for it, and all the sans text is typeset using the regular style.

Both of these fonts are stored in .ttc TrueType collection files, and it seems like `mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern=Optima*` yields:

```
optima          optimaregular   /System/Library/Fonts/Optima.ttc   index:  4
optimanormal    optimaregular   /System/Library/Fonts/Optima.ttc   index:  4
optimaregular   optimaregular   /System/Library/Fonts/Optima.ttc   index:  4
```

and `mtxrun` for Baskerville shows a similar result.  Both runs reference an index number, but it seems like ConTeXt is only finding the one style instead of all of them.

What do I need to do to get ConTeXt to find the other styles?

EDIT: Here's what I've found after further investigation.

The `simplefonts` module had lent the impression that things were working correctly for me, but looking at the log file, `simplefonts` appears to fallback on the librebaskerville font that came with TeXLive.

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\setmainfont[Baskerville]
```

Using other system fonts that live `.ttc` files seems to produce a similar result with fallbacks from the TeX tree being used if a similar name is found.

The Arial font on my system is separated by style into individual `.ttf` files.  `simplefonts` finds them correctly, and the newer `\definefontfamily` method also works as expected.

Additionally, I tried defining my own Baskerville typescript with the following:

```
\starttypescript [serif] [baskerville]
  \definefontsynonym [Baskerville-Roman]          [name:Baskerville]
  \definefontsynonym [Baskerville-Bold]           [name:Baskerville-Bold]       
  \definefontsynonym [Baskerville-Italic]         [name:Baskerville-Italic]     
  \definefontsynonym [Baskerville-Bold-Italic]    [name:Baskerville-BoldItalic] 
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [baskerville]
  \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
  \definefontsynonym [Serif]                   [Baskerville-Roman]                   
  \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic]             [Baskerville-Italic]                  
  \definefontsynonym [SerifBold]               [Baskerville-Bold]                    
  \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic]         [Baskerville-Bold-Italic]             
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Baskerville]
  \definetypeface [Baskerville] [rm] [serif] [baskerville] [default] 
\stoptypescript

\usetypescript[Baskerville]
\setupbodyfont[Baskerville]
```

But that method seems to also find the fallbacks that `simplefonts` found instead of using the various styles provided by the system font.

Comment: Is this something ConTeXt can generally do? Does it work with other `.ttc`s and it is just these particular fonts which are a problem?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58129/use-otf-ttf-in-context-mkiv-luatex help? Or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141056/context-using-system-installed-truetype-opentype-fonts?rq=1?

Comment: I've added some more information based on further research.  As far as I can tell, all `.ttc`s seem to provide only one style for ConTeXt, unless I'm setting things up incorrectly.

Comment: Also, a quick test with `lualatex` appears to have some method of indexing into the `.ttc` file to get the different styles instead of just one of them (I think the one with the 0 index position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of ConTeXt are you using? I am using `2015.08.13` on Mac and the following example:

```
\definefontfamily[myfamily][serif][Baskerville]
\definefontfamily[myfamily][sans][Optima]
\setupbodyfont[myfamily]

\starttext

Hello \sans{World}

\stoptext
```

works correctly.

```
pdffonts test.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
PKVICD+Baskerville                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     16  0
QZBUCL+Optima-Regular                CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     17  0
```

A more detailed example:

```
\definefontfamily[myfamily][serif][Baskerville]
\definefontfamily[myfamily][sans][Optima]
\setupbodyfont[myfamily]

\starttext

\bold{Hello} \italic{world} \bolditalic{Hello World} Hello World

{\ss \bold{Hello} \italic{world} \bolditalic{Hello World} Hello World}

\stoptext
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I'm using `2015.05.18` from the latest MacTeX release.  The second example above gives me one line of all boldface "Hello World", and a second line of all regular-sans "Hello World".

Comment: @Ben: it may be a good idea to check context stanalone. I have always had a had time with context on texlive (which mactex is based on)

Comment: looking into context standalone did seem to fix the problem for a time, but it still crops up if I manually rebuild the font cache with `mtxrun --script font --reload`.  After I do that, I get back to finding only one style in a `.ttc` file unless I manually delete the cache files and start from scratch.